# Android Speech Recognition do not recognize short words

Tags: android, speech-recognition

we develop Android apps for blind people and we use speech recognition through SpeechRecognizer class using Italian language. In the last days we are facing a problem: if we use online recognition, many single and short words aren't recognized at all (for example in Italian "punto", "sì") and the SpeechRegognition listener always returns ERROR 7 . Using offline speech recognition the problem seems to disappear, but we need internet connection so we are going online!
Thank you

I expect that the online Speech recognition recognize all words, even a single word.

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution? How can I enable only offline speech recognition?